# What does \0 mean in sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, regex-group

I have the following code:

```
echo "12. Chapter Name" | sed -n -E "s/([0-9]{2})\.[[:space:]].*/\1/p"
```

It prints `12` as expected, since `\1` refers to the first capturing group.

However, if `\0` is used instead of `\1`, the output is `12. Chapter Name`, the entire input string is printed.

It seems that as long as the regex found a match, `\0` prints the entire input string. Is this correct?

I'm running Debian 10.2.

Comment: I think you have `sed -n -E "s/([0-9]{2})\.[[:space:]].*/\1/p"`

Comment: `\0` or (`$0` for the tools that use `$n` to identify the capturing groups) is the string that matches the entire `regex`. Not only in `sed`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Indeed I mistyped. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\0` is a placeholder for the whole match value.

Note that capturing group indices start with `1` and go up until `9` in POSIX regex patterns. The zeroth group is the whole match.

Also, instead of `\0`, it is more common - and probably more portable - to use `&` in `sed`.

```
echo "12. Chapter Name" | sed -n -E "s/([0-9]{2})\.[[:space:]].*/\0/p"
```

is equal to

```
echo "12. Chapter Name" | sed -n -E "s/([0-9]{2})\.[[:space:]].*/&/p"
```

You may read more about `&` at [*Using `&` as the matched string*](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-3).